# How to use sendEmailVerification() method

Tags: firebase, dart, flutter, firebase-authentication

Trying to setup the **firebase_auth** package for Firebase
Email/Password Authentication method in Flutter, but need help with email verification.

I came accross the **sendEmailVerification();** method provided by firebase_auth package, but need some advice on setting it up. Does anyone have a working code example to follow please?

```
// From firebase_auth package docs > https://pub.dartlang.org/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/FirebaseUser/sendEmailVerification.html

Future<void> sendEmailVerification() async {
  // TODO(amirh): remove this on when the invokeMethod update makes it to stable Flutter.
  // https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/26431
  // ignore: strong_mode_implicit_dynamic_method
  await FirebaseAuth.channel.invokeMethod(
      'sendEmailVerification', <String, String>{'app': _app.name});
}
```

Any help, advice, guidance with setting it up properly and working sample code to follow if possible would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This method will work if you make a `FirebaseUser`. It can be used like this:

```dart
await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword (
  email: //wherever you set their email,
  password: //wherever you set their password,
).then((FirebaseUser user) {
  //If a user is successfully created with an appropriate email
if (user != null){
  user.sendEmailVerification();
}
})
.catchError();
```

Comment: Thanks for this! didn't realize `FirebaseUser` should be made.

Comment: @Effie You're welcome! Consider accepting this answer so other people who have this problem know how to solve it!

Comment: @R.Duggan does using sendEmailVerification() automation sign in the user?

Comment: @WilliamHumphries I believe you will need to take the password and email that they signed in with and get an `AuthCredential` from them to get an access token so you can confirm it is them. For more info have a look at the documentation of the flutter firebase_auth package at https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_auth

Comment: This is perfect, but how to prevent user from navigating to home screen without verifying their email first?

Comment: This solution will send an Email verification, but it will also log the user in immediately, without waiting for the email address to be verified.  Am I missing something ?

Comment: @AliMohsin you just need to verify using user.emailVerified if thats true then navigate the user otherwise dont navigate it.